# TYPO3 Exception Viewhelpers after upgrade to v11

Tags: typo3, view-helpers, typo3-11.x

After I have updated my TYPO3 System to v11.4 and PHP8, I recognized, that all my extensions, which include ViewHelpers are not working anymore. If I call the Backend of these extensions, I got a TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception:

> PHP Warning: Undefined array key "selected" in
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\fluid\Classes\ViewHelpers\Be\Menus\ActionMenuItemViewHelper.php
> line 116

In the log I got

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1476107295:
> PHP Warning: Undefined array key "selected" in
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\fluid\Classes\ViewHelpers\Be\Menus\ActionMenuItemViewHelper.php
> line 116 | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception thrown in file
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\ErrorHandler.php in
> line 145. Requested URL:
> https://test.url.de/typo3/module/tools/TeaserBeteaser?token=--AnonymizedToken--

I have absolute no idea, where the array key `selected` is coming from!

This has to be something to do with the update, because these extensions were working well.

I'm using Windows and IIS.

Has somebody any idea what has changed or how I can figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I created a [bug report at forge](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/95283) for this issue as this is a bug in TYPO3 core.

With PHP8 an exceptions is triggered instead of a notice ([see docs])[2](https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration80.incompatible.php).

There are quite a few places which still need to be fixed in TYPO3 Core and extensions. Therefore I propose to use PHP 7.4 and upgrade to PHP8 later.

Comment: Hallo Georg, I can confirm, that the problem is related to PHP 8. Thanks!

Comment: FYI has been fixed with https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/commit/1ec67c42245911c3c348674413949441261bda45

Comment: I will test it, maybe tonight. But does it make sense to go back to PHP8?

Comment: the core team is happy to get issues for every exception which is still not handled but therefore you need to use the dev-master version and not the released 11 version and you need to report issues at forge. otherwise I propose to stay on php74

Comment: I tested it and it is working. Thank you. I am still in the test phase with my V11 system. So I can load the dev-master version, as long I am not going online with V11.

Comment: Georg, I have installed github and from `https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3` downloaded the TYPO3. I am not able to open `.../Typo3` and get the following error message if I call the WEB-Site `Warning: require(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\composer/../../typo3/sysext/core/Resources/PHP/GlobalDebugFunctions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 69`.  The original installation was from zip and not from composer.